# Geometric Progression: How to solve for $n$ in the following equation $\frac {5^n-1}4 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$

Tags: geometric-progressions

Solve $$\frac {5^n-1}4 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$

How to find the minimum value of $n$ that can satisfy above equation?

Comment: It is difficult to read the expression. Please, fix it.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Edited

Comment: The minimum value of $n$ is not large. You can find the value by testing $n=1,2,\dots$.

Comment: Its a large set

Answer (score 3):

Multiply by $4$:
$$5^n-1\equiv 1\pmod 7. $$
Add $1$:
$$5^n\equiv 2\pmod 7. $$
The first few powers of $5$, modulo $7$, are: $1,5,4,6,2,3,1$. Hence the period is $6$ (as might be expected) and we conclude
$$\frac{5^n-1}4\equiv 2\pmod 7\iff n\equiv 4\pmod 6. $$

Comment: can you please elaborate last line after period. How did you come up with number 4?

Comment: Can you please help? I was wondering how did you come up with the conclusion n = 4 (mod 9)

Answer (score 1):

Just define the values of this expression for every $n$:
$$5^n=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }\;n\equiv 0\mod 6\\ 5&\text{if }\;n\equiv 1\mod 6\\4&\text{if }\;n\equiv 2\mod 6\\6&\text{if }\;n\equiv 3\mod 6\\ 2&\text{if }\;n\equiv 4\mod 6\\ 3&\text{if }\;n\equiv 5\mod 6 \end{cases} \pmod 7$$
hence $\;5^n-1\equiv 0,\:4,\:3,\:5,\:1,\:2$ respectively. On the other hand
$$\frac{5^n-1}4\equiv 2(5^n-1)\equiv\begin{cases}2&\text{if }\;n\equiv 0\mod 6\\ 3&\text{if }\;n\equiv 1\mod 6\\4&\text{if }\;n\equiv 2\mod 6\\5&\text{if }\;n\equiv 3\mod 6\\ 4&\text{if }\;n\equiv 4\mod 6\\ 6&\text{if }\;n\equiv 5\mod 6\end{cases} \pmod 7$$

Comment: actually, n can be a very large value so I was looking for a formula. I had done this but it is very slow

Comment: You don't have to calculate all powers of $5$:  just have to replace $5^n$ with $5^{n\bmod 6}$.